# Typescript: cannot access namespaced interface

Tags: typescript

Im not quite sure what is going on here but I can't access an interface that seems to be exported from the TSServer protocol (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/server/protocol.ts)

To take a step back, I am working on a project where the code does this...

```
if (renameResults) {
  if (renameResults.info.canRename) {
    // do stuff ... no errors
  }
} else {
  this.printErr(renameResults.info.localizedErrorMessage);
}
```

If you look at the TSServer protocol for the type you will see that this is a union type of `RenameInfoSuccess | RenameInfoFailure` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/server/protocol.ts#L1096)

the code above gives me the error `Property 'localizedErrorMessage' does not exist on type 'RenameInfo'. Property 'localizedErrorMessage' does not exist on type 'RenameInfoSuccess'`

but it cannot be `RenameInfoSuccess` because I had already checked for it to be false, right? I have tried every combination I could think of checking the attributes of `info` but nothing has worked. I thought I would try to get at the interface and use `as` or `instanceof` but I cannot seem to import the interface any way either....

How can I make the compiler happy here?

EDIT: added another line that made the typecheck more precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `if (renameResults) {` checks for truthy/falsey, it won't narrow your specific union type. It *would* narrow a union of `... | null` to remove the `null`.

You will need to write a custom type guard to narrow the union type.

For example:

```
function isRenameSuccess(obj: RenameInfoSuccess | RenameInfoFailure) : obj is RenameInfoSuccess {
    return obj.canRename;
}
```

This will narrow the type to `RenameInfoSuccess` in the `if` and `RenameInfoFailure` in the `else` when used like this:

```
if (isRenameSuccess(renameResults)) {
    // renameResults: RenameInfoSuccess
} else {
    // renameResults: RenameInfoFailure
}
```

You could also go the whole hog and turn those two types into a [Discriminated Union](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZEtADwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA23&ots=dpYMnAQkH-&dq=%22pro%20typescript%22%20discriminated%20union&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q&f=false) type, which it very nearly is.

Comment: Two things... 1. I made a mistake in my post and the typecheck that is already present is more precise (see the edited post). 2. I wanted to do exactly what you said, but I can't figure out how to import the types from the 'typescript/lib/protocol', they seem to be hidden or internal or something

Comment: scratch that last comment, it is working. IDK what happened before but it was telling me the interface type didn't exist. Thanks

Comment: No problem: 1. The check you are using isn't a type check, it checks the value. If you were using a discriminated union, it would work as you expect (i.e. the compiler would know that the property you are using is the discriminator). 2. You can set the library items you want using your tsconfig file in the `lib` option: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html